# Phenomena in Pokemon Black and White

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-fifth-generation

I have some questions about phenomena, specifically for Black and White.

1. If you **stand** next to some tiles of grass, is it possible that suddenly a tile of rustling grass will appear just by time passing? Or can a tile of rustling grass only appear when you make a step, so you have to **keep walking / running / cycling** for the rustling grass to appear?
2. Similarly, does the grass stop rustling if you stand next to it for too long, or if you make to many steps?
3. When the rustling grass tile appears in the middle of some other grass tiles, you have to go through those first to get to the rustling one. Is there any way to avoid encountering wild Pokemon until you get to the rustling tile, and then step onto the rustling grass and encounter that Pokemon?

Comment: For 3, use repels

Comment: Will it not repel the Pokemon in the rustling grass tile?

Comment: Pretty sure it won't. That's how I would usually get chains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, you have to be moving for rustling tiles to spawn.
2. Per Bulbapedia:

> A phenomenon will vanish after it is encountered or if the player picks up a visible item, interacts with an NPC, or exits the area or room entirely; it will also vanish if an NPC steps on it.

3. Repels stop the random encounters but not the rustling grass encounter.

Comment: You beat me to it. @mIllIbyte, check out the first few paragraphs of the [Bulbapedia page on Phenomenon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Phenomenon).